# Old IP address is getting loaded for Site Admin

Tags: phpmyadmin, dns, ip, propagation

I have near to nothing knowledge in web development. I tried to move all contents from a old server to a new one. The IP address is also changed. When I am trying to go to the new site it works. But as soon as I try to login to SiteAdmin the previous IP loads up. So, its like this the site loads up at **http://NewIP** but **SiteAddress/siteadmin = oldip/siteadmin**. Other than that PHPMyAdmin is loading up at the new IP. I have tried to go through the index.php and some other php and js file with no luck. Could someone please direct me which file I should be looking for.The site has been developed following bootstrap framework.

Comment: How long ago did you update the DNS record? What was the TTL of the record?

Comment: what php framework is being used on your site? There must be some hard coded IP address on your siteadmin page's code or in your router config file.

Comment: without seeing the particular code all we can do is guess randomly

Comment: SO is for programming questions. Questions about using third-party server administration applications are not really on-topic. ServerFault.com would be a better place to ask for help.

Comment: @JCm Kohana framework has been used.